# Find out largest string value size for keys in Redis database

Tags: python, redis

I need to look at our Redis cache and see what the size of our largest stored value is. I am experienced with Python or can use the `redis-cli` directly. Is there a way to iterate all the keys in the database  so I can then inspect the size of each value?

It looks like SCAN is the way to iterate through the keys, but I'm still working out how to put this to use to get the sizes of the values and store a maximum as I go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you mentioned `redis-cli` as an option, it has a build it function that does pretty much what you ask for (and much more).

`redis-cli --bigkeys`

```
# Scanning the entire keyspace to find biggest keys as well as
# average sizes per key type. You can use -i 0.1 to sleep 0.1 sec
# per 100 SCAN commands (not usually needed).
```

Here is a sample of the summery output:

```
Sampled 343799 keys in the keyspace!
Total key length in bytes is 9556361 (avg len 27.80)

Biggest string found '530f8dc7c7b3b:39:string:87929' has 500 bytes
Biggest list found '530f8d5a17b26:9:list:11211' has 500 items
Biggest set found '530f8da856e1e:75:set:65939' has 500 members
Biggest hash found '530f8d619a0af:86:hash:16911' has 500 fields
Biggest zset found '530f8d4a9ce31:45:zset:315' has 500 members

68559 strings with 17136672 bytes (19.94% of keys, avg size 249.96)
68986 lists with 17326343 items (20.07% of keys, avg size 251.16)
68803 sets with 17236635 members (20.01% of keys, avg size 250.52)
68622 hashs with 17272144 fields (19.96% of keys, avg size 251.70)
68829 zsets with 17241902 members (20.02% of keys, avg size 250.50)
```

You can view a complete output example [here](https://gist.github.com/michael-grunder/9257326)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution which uses [redis's built-in scripting capabilities](http://redis.io/commands/eval):

```
local longest
local cursor = "0"

repeat
  local ret = redis.call("scan", cursor)
  cursor = ret[1]
  for _, key in ipairs(ret[2]) do
    local length = redis.pcall("strlen", key)
    if type(length) == "number" then
      if longest == nil or length > longest then
        longest = length
      end
    end
  end
until cursor == "0"

return longest
```

This should run faster than the Python code you provide, Ben Roberts, particularly because the Lua script uses [`STRLEN`](http://redis.io/commands/strlen) over [`GET`](http://redis.io/commands/get) + Python's `len`.

Comment: I believe you can't SCAN from Lua due to it's indeterministic nature.

Comment: @ItamarHaber: Is there anything in the documentation about that? I can't seem to find anything that recommends against using `SCAN` from instead of a Lua script.

Comment: IIRC it is only implicitly implied, but try running the script and you'll see for yourself - you'll get an error immediately because of it. Also, another pitfall with that script and like I commented above, is that you'll get an error if you hit non-string keys.

Comment: @ItamarHaber: I am getting no errors when executing the script (redis v2.8.17). What version of redis are you using? You will also notice that the non-string issue is handled in the script.

Comment: I bow at your awesomeness - you are totally right :) SCAN's non-deterministic nature is only a problem if the script performs a write (which it doesn't). In my defense I can only claim that my previous comments were written late at night on my mobile...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Looks like lua is powerful and easy to pick up (similar to python/ruby). I adjusted my python solution to use strlen instead of get--wasn't aware of that function.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out a basic idea, using the [redis-py library](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py)

```
import redis
r= redis.StrictRedis(...)
max_len = 0
for k in r.scan_iter():
  try:
    val_len = r.strlen(k)
  except:
    continue
  if val_len > max_len:
    max_len = val_len
print max_len
```

Comment: That looks like the right approach, but note that GET is only for string values, whereas your keys could contains other data structures - perhaps checking the type before trying to get the length would be better. You can also use DUMP for a rough estimation of size regardless the data structure.

Comment: Yep, i realized that once I run it. Added error handling to just move on from those that are not string values. Thanks